# Slick 2D first trial error

Tags: java, slick

I followed some advices to learn Slick2D and when I started doing the "SimpleGame" I got my first error. Does anyone have any idea of what is it and how to fix?

```
Sun Dec 26 23:09:12 GMT-03:00 2010 INFO:Slick Build #274
Sun Dec 26 23:09:12 GMT-03:00 2010 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.0b1
Sun Dec 26 23:09:12 GMT-03:00 2010 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1024 x 768 x 16 @60Hz
Sun Dec 26 23:09:12 GMT-03:00 2010 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 800 x 600 x 0 @0Hz
Sun Dec 26 23:09:12 GMT-03:00 2010 ERROR:Could not find a valid pixel format
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not find a valid pixel format
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplayPeerInfo.initDC(WindowsDisplayPeerInfo.java:54)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:158)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:299)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:800)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.tryCreateDisplay(AppGameContainer.java:299)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.access$000(AppGameContainer.java:34)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$2.run(AppGameContainer.java:364)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:345)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
 at SimpleGame.main(SimpleGame.java:38)
Exception in thread "main" org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Failed to initialise the LWJGL display
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:375)
 at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
 at SimpleGame.main(SimpleGame.java:38)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a quick Bing search and got the following [forum post](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,2888.0.html) and [another one](http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?t=1674). Note that the problem is `Failed to initialise the LWJGL display` and according to both forums this could be fixed by adding the following line:

```
-Dorg.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL=true
```

to the `VM Arguments` of your IDE. I am not a Java developer, so I am not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: I'll try that too. Thanks! ps: didn't know people use Bing to search instead of google

Comment: @pringlesinn I actually use both search engines. I have been mostly using Bing recently, but sometimes switch to Google when I don't get good results for a certain query :)

Comment: @pringlesinn I am happy everything worked out and good luck with learning Slick2D :)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great idea, software OpenGL is too slow for anything other than quick experiments.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig @pringlesinn you are correct Joe. The original problem seems to be that the OpenGL Hardware drivers are probably not installed properly. This is more of a partial fix while he is using it for learning purposes. The solution came from a moderator on the LWJGL forum though, which led me to believe that this might be an acceptable solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally unfamiliar with Slick2D, but it looks like you're requesting a 800x600 fullscreen resolution when your monitor / video card only supports 1024x768.

Comment: Once I get home I'll try it, and I'll let you know.